# Angular Module Federation. Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: container.init is not a function

Tags: angular, webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation

I created two angular module federation apps using [angular module federation plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-architects/module-federation) but faced with an error `Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: container.init is not a function` after I load the remote component [error image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75QTL.png)

I found this [github issue thread](https://github.com/angular-architects/module-federation-plugin/issues/96) with the solution to add `scriptType: 'text/javascript'` in `output` section of `webpack.config.js` file but it does not work for me.

If you need more details about apps here are links for [host](https://github.com/ytworkgithub/angular-module-federation-host) and [remote](https://github.com/ytworkgithub/angular-module-federation-remote) repositories.

`@angular/cli` version is `13.0.2`

`@angular-architects/module-federation` version is `14.2.3`.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Made module federation work for the Angular standalone project.

**Just installed Webpack `5.72.0` as a dev dependency.**

Webpack was not listed in the dependencies of `package.json` and I took a look at its version via the `node_modules` folder, it was `5.64.0`.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `angular v14.1.1` and `"@angular-architects/module-federation": "^14.3.10", "@angular-architects/module-federation-tools": "^14.3.10", "ngx-build-plus": "^14.0.0"`.

After commented `library` property section from `remote mfe app`  `webpack.config.js` .It's working for me.

```
module.exports = withModuleFederationPlugin({
  name: "angular14",
  // library: { type: "var", name: "angular14" },
  filename: "remoteEntry.js",
  exposes: {
    './web-components': './src/bootstrap.ts',
  },

  shared: {
    ...shareAll({ singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: 'auto' }),
  },

});
```

Not sure what is the reason but may help someone this also.